# Iterating over paginated data with an unknown number of pages with Python requests from BSE API

Tags: python, json, pandas, python-requests

I am trying to fetch data from a URL that uses pagination. I fetch the paginated data using the following payload:

```py
payload = {
'Pageno': '7',
'strCat': '-1',
'strPrevDate': '20220122',
'strScrip': '',
'strSearch': 'P',
'strToDate': '20220122',
'strType': 'C'}
```

I do not know how many pages are there. I want to take them one by one until I end up with a page that doesn't exist. The code to extract the data is as follows:

```py
jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()
```

How can I can ensure that I make this request conditional to existence of the URL?

The URL is:

```py
url = 'https://api.bseindia.com/BseIndiaAPI/api/AnnGetData/w'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36'}
```

Comment: What is the `date` variable? Can you give sample values for this variable?

Comment: date ="20220122"     trye with Pageno   1-6 as 7 may not exist

Comment: corrected date by editing in original question as well

Comment: Use status_code() method. 200 means request was successful,  404 NOT FOUND status means that the resource you were looking for was not found.

Comment: `requests.Response.status_code` is a property, not a method, so you don't need `()`

Comment: Iam bit new to this area. (old time programmer) . can you just write a line of code as I am still learning.  If statement or something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BSE's API will return 200 OK for any positive value of `Pageno`, even if you've read past the end of the data. You should loop over each page, and then break out whenever you encounter an empty list (which indicates that you've reached the end of the data).

```py
import requests

payload = {
    'Pageno': 1,
    'strCat': '-1',
    'strPrevDate': '20220122',
    'strScrip': '',
    'strSearch': 'P',
    'strToDate':   '20220122',
    'strType': 'C'
}

url = 'https://api.bseindia.com/BseIndiaAPI/api/AnnGetData/w'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36'}

data = []
should_fetch_next_page = True
while should_fetch_next_page:
    print(f"Fetching page {payload['Pageno']} ...")
    jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()
    if jsonData["Table"]:
        data.extend(jsonData["Table"])
        payload['Pageno'] += 1
    else:
        should_fetch_next_page = False
        
print(data)
```

Comment: This worked quite well. How to accept this answer or solution please.

Comment: No problem! Have a good day. :)